# SSE reduction of float vector

Tags: c++, sum, sse, simd, reduction

How can I get sum elements (reduction) of float vector using sse intrinsics?

Simple serial code:

```
void(float *input, float &result, unsigned int NumElems)
{
     result = 0;
     for(auto i=0; i<NumElems; ++i)
         result += input[i];
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Did you actually look at the generated code? At least my experience with gcc is that it does a pretty good job at doing SSE instructions when possible - but it may require -O3.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Typically you generate 4 partial sums in your loop and then just sum horizontally across the 4 elements after the loop, e.g.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdint>
#include <emmintrin.h>

float vsum(const float *a, int n)
{
    float sum;
    __m128 vsum = _mm_set1_ps(0.0f);
    assert((n & 3) == 0);
    assert(((uintptr_t)a & 15) == 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 4)
    {
        __m128 v = _mm_load_ps(&a[i]);
        vsum = _mm_add_ps(vsum, v);
    }
    vsum = _mm_hadd_ps(vsum, vsum);
    vsum = _mm_hadd_ps(vsum, vsum);
    _mm_store_ss(&sum, vsum);
    return sum;
}
```

Note: for the above example `a` must be 16 byte aligned and `n` must be a multiple of 4. If the alignment of `a` can not be guaranteed then use `_mm_loadu_ps` instead of `_mm_load_ps`. If `n` is not guaranteed to be a multiple of 4 then add a scalar loop at the end of the function to accumulate any remaining elements.

Comment: If the input array is potentially large, it's worth having a scalar loop at the start, too, that runs 0-3 times until the input is aligned on a 16B boundary for the SSE loop.  Then you won't have loads that cross cache/page lines slowing down your loop.  And it can use `ADDPS` with a memory operand, which can potentially micro-fuse, reducing overhead.  Also, you could get 2 or 4 dependency chains going, by using multiple accumulators, so your loop could sustain 1 vector FP add per cycle, instead of 1 per (latency of `ADDPS` = 3).

Comment: @PeterCordes Can you explain about `_mm_add_ps` with a memory operand? Do you mean a pointer argument rather than an `__m128`?

Comment: @user2023370: `addps` the asm instruction, not `_mm_add_ps` the intrinsic. 
 I'm talking about the compiler's code-gen options.  e.g. `addps xmm0, [rdi]` (folding a `_mm_load_ps` into a memory operand that can micro-fuse in the decoders) instead of  `movups xmm1, [rdi]` / `addps xmm0, xmm1`. (`_mm_loadu_ps` can't fold unless you have AVX to allow unaligned memory operands.)  Of course you still definitely want multiple accumulators to hide FP add latency: see [Why does mulss take only 3 cycles on Haswell, different from Agner's instruction tables?](//stackoverflow.com/q/45113527) for more.

Comment: Thanks. That's very helpful. I read your answer to the other question too. Can I check my understanding: if I add one accumulator to the answer above, we might have a `v1` and `v2`, along with a `vsum1` and `vsum2`, and the loop increment by 8 rather than 4?