# sse sum of unsigned long long array

Tags: c++, sum, sse, simd, uint64

based on [SSE reduction of float vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761154/sse-reduction-of-float-vector) I tried to sum the array of **unsigned long long** but unfortunatelly without any success.

```
uint64_t vsum_uint64 (uint64_t *a, int n)
{
    uint64_t sum;    // lets say sum fits
    __m128 vsum = _mm_set1_ps(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 2) {    // 2 unit64 in single __m128
        __m128 v = _mm_loadl_epi64(&a[i]);
        vsum = _mm_add_epi64(vsum, v);
    }

    _mm_store_ss(&sum, vsum);
    uint64_t *p = &vsum;
    sum+=*(p+1);

    // vsum = _mm_hadd_ps(vsum, vsum);
    // vsum = _mm_hadd_ps(vsum, vsum);
    return sum;
}
```

This should be quite right, but gcc still can't compile it. I searched for answers, but haven't found any.

This is what gcc says:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘uint64_t vsum_uint64(const uint64_t*, int)’:
main.cpp:73:35: error: cannot convert ‘const uint64_t* {aka const long unsigned int*}’ to ‘const __m128i* {aka const __vector(2) long long int*}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘__m128i _mm_loadl_epi64(const __m128i*)’
main.cpp:74:31: error: cannot convert ‘__m128 {aka __vector(4) float}’ to ‘__m128i {aka __vector(2) long long int}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘__m128i _mm_add_epi64(__m128i, __m128i)’
main.cpp:77:25: error: cannot convert ‘uint64_t* {aka long unsigned int*}’ to ‘float*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void _mm_store_ss(float*, __m128)’
main.cpp:78:17: error: cannot convert ‘__m128* {aka __vector(4) float*}’ to ‘uint64_t* {aka long unsigned int*}’ in initialization
```

Can you help mi please? I'd really appreciate it

Thanks

Comment: The compiler errors are straightforward. You are missing type casts on various pointer types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are a few things:

1. use `__m128i` instead of `__m128`
2. you can zero-initialize `vsum` using `__m128i vsum = _mm_setzero_si128()`;
3. for data load, cast to the proper __m128i type and use the packed-load version (_mm_loadl_epi64 only loads one 64-bits integer). so, either

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 2) {    // 2 uint64 in single __m128i
       __m128i v = _mm_loadu_si128(reinterpret_cast<__m128i*>(&a[i]));
   ```

   or

   ```
   __m128i* pa = reinterpret_cast<__m128i*>(a);
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 2) {    // 2 uint64 in single __m128i
       __m128i v = _mm_loadu_si128(pa);
       pa++;
   ```
4. finally you may be able to assign to sum using `sum = vsum.m128i_u64[0] + vsum.m128i_u64[1];` if there's a union defined for it (there is under windows/Visual-Studio, but you are using a different environment).