# Need help optimizing speed for a loop/dot-product function in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, euclidean-distance, dot-product

I've identified a function in a tightloop that's responsible for 50% of the time in my program(finding nearest neighbors). It calculates the euclidean distance between two unit vectors. Is there any way to make this run faster? (currently I am using gcc's `-march=native` and `-ffast-math` flags)

```
template<typename T>
  static inline T distance(const T* x, const T* y, int f) {
    T pp = 0, qq = 0, pq = 0;
    for (int z = 0; z < f; z++, x++, y++) {
      pp += (*x) * (*x);
      qq += (*y) * (*y);
      pq += (*x) * (*y);
    }
    T ppqq = pp * qq;
    if (ppqq > 0) return 2.0 - 2.0 * pq / sqrt(ppqq);
    else return 2.0;
  }
```

Comment: is this used for multiple types or T is actually only ever a single type?

Comment: Presumably `T` must be `float` or `double`? Can `x` and `y` alias? Is `f` bounded above?

Comment: How frequent/fast is the call to `sqrt`?

Comment: you could initialize with the first elements and start the loop at 1

Comment: "I am using gcc's -march=native and -ffast-math flags" - as well as `-O2` or `-O3` I assume?

Comment: @JesperJuhl yes, `-O3` is used as well.

Comment: @SamerTufail  yes, they are floating point calculations. 
f is bounded above. what do you mean by `x` and `x` alias?

Comment: @SamerTufail it is actually used for single type, which is `float`. But since this C++ template shouldn't affect the performance like java's generics.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo very frequent, but still not as bad as the loop above it. That loop is just doing do-products.

Comment: @Beginner i think you're joking, but that is actually funny.. :)

Comment: Have you tried building with `-flto`?

Comment: How about adding a template parameter for `int f` and specializing for T=float/double and f=1,2,3,4? You could completely unroll that loop.

Comment: How about using SSE instructions, similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761154/sse-reduction-of-float-vector

Comment: @Beginner  I've tried loop unrolling and SSE for calculating dot-products, and with the right compiler flags, there is not much improvement. If you want to see the benchmarks, my code for that is here: https://github.com/ijklr/sse

Comment: @JesperJuhl what does that flag do?

Comment: @ijklr As the documentation ("man g++") would have told you faster than typing that question, it enables link time optimization.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thanks, sorry I was using a mac and didn't have `man g++` in the terminal. but I sshed into a linux machine and see it that `-flto` flag doc now.

Comment: The correct answer t this question depends on typical values of `z`. is it typically 4, 4000 or 4.000.000 ?

Answer (score 1):

This code is higly paralelizable, you could try to use [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) or a small thread to do the computations in different threads.

```
template<typename T>
  static inline T distance(const T[] x, const T[] y, int f) {
    T pp = 0, qq = 0, pq = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel for private(x,z) reduction(*:pp)
    for (int z = 0; z < f; z++, x++) {
      pp += (*x) * (*x);
    }
  }
```

OpenMP is a Paralelization library that relies on Pragmas for paralelizing code, it's really common in scientific computing. You can easily create threads by specifiying a pragma over the statement you wanna paralelize.

The simplest format is

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    paralelized code here
}
```

This will take care of creating the threads, executing the paralelized code and joiining the threads back for you with a simple #pragma definition.

Comment: Would be nice to briefly explain `#pragma omp parallel for private(x,z) reduction(+:pp)` for people unfamiliar with OpenMP

Comment: Agree with @VittorioRomeo .. I don't know what that means as well. It'd be nice to know.

Comment: edited for more information

Comment: Thanks @TomazCanabrava   one more thing, can you explain what `private(x,z) reduction(+:pp)` does?

Comment: private means that the variables are private of teach thread, and reduction says what operator should be used on the reduction, and the variable to store the calculation.