# Accessing the fields of a __m128i variable in a portable way

Tags: simd, sse

I am trying to use SIMD instructions to speed up the sum of elements in an array of uint8_t (i.e., sum reduction). For that purpose, I am replicating the most voted answer in this question:

[Sum reduction of unsigned bytes without overflow, using SSE2 on Intel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932550/sum-reduction-of-unsigned-bytes-without-overflow-using-sse2-on-intel?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The procedure for the sum reduction shown in that answer is this:

```
uint16_t sum_32(const uint8_t a[32])
{
    __m128i zero = _mm_xor_si128(zero, zero);
    __m128i sum0 = _mm_sad_epu8(
                        zero,
                        _mm_load_si128(reinterpret_cast<const __m128i*>(a)));
    __m128i sum1 = _mm_sad_epu8(
                        zero,
                        _mm_load_si128(reinterpret_cast<const __m128i*>(&a[16])));
    __m128i sum2 = _mm_add_epi16(sum0, sum1);
    __m128i totalsum = _mm_add_epi16(sum2, _mm_shuffle_epi32(sum2, 2));
    return totalsum.m128i_u16[0];
}
```

My problem is that the return operation (`totalsum.m128i_u16[0]`) seems to be available only for Microsoft, but I am using UNIX-based platforms.

I reviewed the list of SIMD intrinsics, and the function `_mm_storeu_ps(a, t)` seems to do something similar to what I require, but `t` has to be a __m128 variable and a `a` float. I tried to use that function by casting my result from __m128i to __m128, but it didn't work.

Is there another way in which I can retrieve the first 16 bits of a __m128i variable and store them into a uint16_t variable?. I am very new to SIMD programming.

BTW, is there a better solution for implementing sum reduction?. That answer is from 9 years ago. I imagine that now are better alternatives.

Comment: I tidied up harold's answer on [Sum reduction of unsigned bytes without overflow, using SSE2 on Intel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10933578) - thanks for pointing out it it was old and weird, using MSVC-specific stuff.  The asm was correct, and I'd seen many good answers from harold, but I didn't notice that was apparently from his early days with intrinsics when I linked it on the problems when linking it other places (like my canonical answer on [Fastest way to do horizontal SSE vector sum (or other reduction)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35270026)).

Comment: Fixed one last thing I missed before: the manual xor-zeroing that reads the variable as part of its own initializer.  Updated the linked answer.

Comment: N.B.: Instead of `_mm_xor_si128(zero, zero)` just use `_mm_setzero_si128()`.

Comment: @chtz: That was one of multiple things I fixed in [the old answer that code was copied from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932550/sum-reduction-of-unsigned-bytes-without-overflow-using-sse2-on-intel/10933578#10933578).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_mm_extract_epi16` for a compile-time known index.

For the first element `_mm_cvtsi128_si32` gives more efficient instructions. This would work, given that:

- `_mm_sad_epu8` fills the the bits 16 thru 63 to zero
- you truncate the result to 16 bits via `uint16_t` return type

Compilers may be able to do this optimization on their own, based on either of the reasons, but not all of them, so it is better to use `_mm_cvtsi128_si32`.

Comment: @AAA: And if you want *all* the elements separately, often storing to an array and looping is good: [print a \_\_m128i variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46752535)  (If you want to sum them, see [Fastest way to do horizontal SSE vector sum (or other reduction)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35270026) - `psadbw` is still optimal.)

Comment: @Alex: compilers couldn't optimize `_mm_extract_epi16(v, 0)` into `movd` unless they could prove that the low dword of the vector was a zero-extended word; maybe you're thinking of `_mm_extract_epi32(v, 0)`.  Since this is doing a `paddw` on `psadbw` results, that will be the case (and for only a couple vectors, `paddw` is wide enough not to truncate the result).

Comment: @PeterCordes, actually clang is able to take advantage of truncation and uses `movd` https://godbolt.org/z/e58arzn4f

Comment: Yup, figured clang might be able to.  The right answer here is to use `movd`; note that it is a psadbw result so your edit unfortunately made your answer more correct but less helpful.

Comment: @PeterCordes, got it, fixed.

Comment: Much better.  BTW, I updated harold's answer on [Sum reduction of unsigned bytes without overflow, using SSE2 on Intel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10933578) to be good, using `paddd` intrinsics instead of `paddw` (so it's extensible to larger arrays), and using a movd intrinsic.  And an `unsigned` return value to avoid making compilers waste instructions truncating / re-widening the `movd` result; looks like we both noticed that problem, too.