# Can counting byte matches between two strings be optimized using SIMD?

Tags: c++, optimization, x86-64, sse, simd

Profiling suggests that this function here is a real bottle neck for my application:

```
static inline int countEqualChars(const char* string1, const char* string2, int size) {
    int r = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
        if (string1[j] == string2[j]) {
            ++r;
        }
    }

    return r;
}
```

Even with `-O3` and `-march=native`, G++ 4.7.2 does not vectorize this function (I checked the assembler output). Now, I'm *not* an expert with SSE and friends, but I think that comparing more than one character at once should be faster. Any ideas on how to speed things up? Target architecture is x86-64.

Comment: What are the inputs typically like?  What size, and are they variable or literal strings?  Also, what's the reason for needing this function--what is its "deeper meaning" in your system?

Comment: did you try using -msse, etc flags? and measuring the performance before and after the fact? See [another example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919304/gcc-sse-code-optimization)

Comment: I tried -msse and did not measure any difference in runtime. Both strings are guaranteed to have identical lengths. Sizes vary wildly though.

Comment: @Petesh: the OP used `-march=native`, which implies whatever `-mfoo` flags his CPU supports.

Comment: @Fanael That's what the doc says, but TBH I don't actually trust `-march=native` to do the right thing (this is from experience on older variants of gcc, this may not actually be the case now)

Comment: By the way, you can also do this faster without SSE2 (even though all x86_64 CPUs support that), using SWAR techniques. The simplest form of this is skipping the byte-by-byte comparisons if two 64-bit words are equal. A more sophisticated form can create a 64-bit word where each byte is 1 if the corresponding bytes in the strings are equal and 0 if not; these words can be processed as with SSE2.

Comment: `Now, I'm not an expert with SSE and friends` -> You provide a clue already. My hint: Grab some introductory material ;) This question seems basically like a plea for code, but expressed rather finely.

Comment: [How to count character occurrences using SIMD](//stackoverflow.com/q/54541129) has an AVX2 version (using a single character instead of a second string, but the vectorization is done identically).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Compiler flags for vectorization:**

`-ftree-vectorize`

`-ftree-vectorize -march=<your_architecture>` (Use all instruction-set extensions available on your computer, not just baseline like SSE2 for x86-64).  Use `-march=native` to optimize for the machine the compiler is running on.)  `-march=<foo>` also sets `-mtune=<foo>`, which is also a good thing.

**Using SSEx intrinsics:**

- Padd and align the buffer to 16 bytes (according to the vector size you're actually going to use)
- Create an accumlator `countU8` with [_mm_set1_epi8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/6e14xhyf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)(0)
- For all n/16 input (sub) vectors, do:

  - Load 16 chars from both strings with [_mm_load_si128](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/x7s4chk3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or [_mm_loadu_si128](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/x7s4chk3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (for unaligned loads)
  - [_mm_cmpeq_epi8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5yc9bc1f%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#vcref_mm_cmpeq_epi8)
    compare the octets in parallel. Each match yields `0xFF` (-1), `0x00` otherwise.
  - Substract the above result vector from `countU8` using [_mm_sub_epi8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tb4wh6zw%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) (minus -1 -> +1)
  - Always after 255 cycles, the 16 8bit counters must be extracted into a larger integer type to prevent overflows. See unpack and horizontal add in this nice answer for how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10930706/1175253

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <cassert>
#include <cstdint>
#include <climits>
#include <cstring>

#include <emmintrin.h>

#ifdef __SSE2__

#if !defined(UINTPTR_MAX) ||  !defined(UINT64_MAX) ||  !defined(UINT32_MAX)
#  error "Limit macros are not defined"
#endif

#if UINTPTR_MAX == UINT64_MAX
    #define PTR_64
#elif UINTPTR_MAX == UINT32_MAX
    #define PTR_32
#else
#  error "Current UINTPTR_MAX is not supported"
#endif

template<typename T>
void print_vector(std::ostream& out,const __m128i& vec)
{
    static_assert(sizeof(vec) % sizeof(T) == 0,"Invalid element size");
    std::cout << '{';
    const T* const end   = reinterpret_cast<const T*>(&vec)-1;
    const T* const upper = end+(sizeof(vec)/sizeof(T));
    for(const T* elem = upper;
        elem != end;
        --elem
    )
    {
        if(elem != upper)
            std::cout << ',';
        std::cout << +(*elem);
    }
    std::cout << '}' << std::endl;
}

#define PRINT_VECTOR(_TYPE,_VEC) do{  std::cout << #_VEC << " : "; print_vector<_TYPE>(std::cout,_VEC);    } while(0)

///@note SSE2 required (macro: __SSE2__)
///@warning Not tested!
size_t counteq_epi8(const __m128i* a_in,const __m128i* b_in,size_t count)
{
    assert(a_in != nullptr && (uintptr_t(a_in) % 16) == 0);
    assert(b_in != nullptr && (uintptr_t(b_in) % 16) == 0);
    //assert(count > 0);


/*
    //maybe not so good with all that branching and additional loop variables

    __m128i accumulatorU8 = _mm_set1_epi8(0);
    __m128i sum2xU64 = _mm_set1_epi8(0);
    for(size_t i = 0;i < count;++i)
    {

        //this operation could also be unrolled, where multiple result registers would be accumulated
        accumulatorU8 = _mm_sub_epi8(accumulatorU8,_mm_cmpeq_epi8(*a_in++,*b_in++));
        if(i % 255 == 0)
        {
            //before overflow of uint8, the counter will be extracted
            __m128i sum2xU16 = _mm_sad_epu8(accumulatorU8,_mm_set1_epi8(0));
            sum2xU64 = _mm_add_epi64(sum2xU64,sum2xU16);

            //reset accumulatorU8
            accumulatorU8 = _mm_set1_epi8(0);
        }
    }

    //blindly accumulate remaining values
    __m128i sum2xU16 = _mm_sad_epu8(accumulatorU8,_mm_set1_epi8(0));
    sum2xU64 = _mm_add_epi64(sum2xU64,sum2xU16);

    //do a horizontal addition of the two counter values
    sum2xU64 = _mm_add_epi64(sum2xU64,_mm_srli_si128(sum2xU64,64/8));

#if defined PTR_64
    return _mm_cvtsi128_si64(sum2xU64);
#elif defined PTR_32
    return _mm_cvtsi128_si32(sum2xU64);
#else
#  error "macro PTR_(32|64) is not set"
#endif

*/

    __m128i sum2xU64 = _mm_set1_epi32(0);
    while(count--)
    {
        __m128i matches     = _mm_sub_epi8(_mm_set1_epi32(0),_mm_cmpeq_epi8(*a_in++,*b_in++));
        __m128i sum2xU16    = _mm_sad_epu8(matches,_mm_set1_epi32(0));
                sum2xU64    = _mm_add_epi64(sum2xU64,sum2xU16);
#ifndef NDEBUG
        PRINT_VECTOR(uint16_t,sum2xU64);
#endif
    }

    //do a horizontal addition of the two counter values
    sum2xU64 = _mm_add_epi64(sum2xU64,_mm_srli_si128(sum2xU64,64/8));
#ifndef NDEBUG
    std::cout << "----------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    PRINT_VECTOR(uint16_t,sum2xU64);
#endif

#if !defined(UINTPTR_MAX) ||  !defined(UINT64_MAX) ||  !defined(UINT32_MAX)
#  error "Limit macros are not defined"
#endif

#if defined PTR_64
    return _mm_cvtsi128_si64(sum2xU64);
#elif defined PTR_32
    return _mm_cvtsi128_si32(sum2xU64);
#else
#  error "macro PTR_(32|64) is not set"
#endif

}

#endif

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    std::vector<__m128i> a(64); // * 16 bytes
    std::vector<__m128i> b(a.size());
    const size_t nBytes = a.size() * sizeof(std::vector<__m128i>::value_type);

    char* const a_out = reinterpret_cast<char*>(a.data());
    char* const b_out = reinterpret_cast<char*>(b.data());

    memset(a_out,0,nBytes);
    memset(b_out,0,nBytes);

    a_out[1023] = 1;
    b_out[1023] = 1;

    size_t equalBytes = counteq_epi8(a.data(),b.data(),a.size());

    std::cout << "equalBytes = " << equalBytes << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

The fastest SSE implementation I got for large and small arrays:

```
size_t counteq_epi8(const __m128i* a_in,const __m128i* b_in,size_t count)
{
    assert((count > 0 ? a_in != nullptr : true) && (uintptr_t(a_in) % sizeof(__m128i)) == 0);
    assert((count > 0 ? b_in != nullptr : true) && (uintptr_t(b_in) % sizeof(__m128i)) == 0);
    //assert(count > 0);

    const size_t maxInnerLoops    = 255;
    const size_t nNestedLoops     = count / maxInnerLoops;
    const size_t nRemainderLoops  = count % maxInnerLoops;

    const __m128i zero  = _mm_setzero_si128();
    __m128i sum16xU8    = zero;
    __m128i sum2xU64    = zero;

    for(size_t i = 0;i < nNestedLoops;++i)
    {
        for(size_t j = 0;j < maxInnerLoops;++j)
        {
            sum16xU8 = _mm_sub_epi8(sum16xU8,_mm_cmpeq_epi8(*a_in++,*b_in++));
        }
        sum2xU64 = _mm_add_epi64(sum2xU64,_mm_sad_epu8(sum16xU8,zero));
        sum16xU8 = zero;
    }

    for(size_t j = 0;j < nRemainderLoops;++j)
    {
        sum16xU8 = _mm_sub_epi8(sum16xU8,_mm_cmpeq_epi8(*a_in++,*b_in++));
    }
    sum2xU64 = _mm_add_epi64(sum2xU64,_mm_sad_epu8(sum16xU8,zero));

    sum2xU64 = _mm_add_epi64(sum2xU64,_mm_srli_si128(sum2xU64,64/8));

#if UINTPTR_MAX == UINT64_MAX
    return _mm_cvtsi128_si64(sum2xU64);
#elif UINTPTR_MAX == UINT32_MAX
    return _mm_cvtsi128_si32(sum2xU64);
#else
#  error "macro PTR_(32|64) is not set"
#endif
}
```

Comment: Instead of ANDing the result from pcmpeqb with a mask and then adding it to an accumulator, you can also subtract the result from the accumulator, saving an instruction in the loop.

Comment: You can do the horizontal add more efficiently using `psadbw` with zero followed by moving high-to-low 64 bits and an add.

Comment: Shall we write this loop ?

Comment: Just added the code I have so far. I tried to implement all suggested improvements.

Comment: My implementation: https://gist.github.com/hdante/5232848 It uses a 255 iteration inner loop. I liked the final inner loop, it's only 7 instructions: https://gist.github.com/hdante/5232856

Comment: On the other hand, I wasn't able to see improvement over the auto vectorized version. I tested both implementations and they are 1% faster than gcc version. I'm afraid the loop is stalling on memory loads. simfoo, do you see any improvement ?

Comment: I added the fastest implementation I currently have.
@hdante: `assert(equalBytes == nBytes);` fails with your implementation in my code (seems, that the remaining `size % something` loops are missing). Regarding memory loads: we may try to `_mm_prefetch()` some cache lines, although I believe that these have considerable effects on older Pentium (II/III) processors only.

Comment: Yes, I only wrote the loop for multiples of 255 vectors for simplicity. Anyway, the final improvement over the original scalar code seems to be minimal.

Comment: [How to count character occurrences using SIMD](//stackoverflow.com/q/54541129) has an AVX2 version using PSADBW outside the inner loop, and multiple accumulators so it can run faster than 1 vector per clock without bottlenecking on 1 cycle `psubb` latency (or 2 cycles on AMD Bulldozer-family).  For a simple version that has SAD inside the inner loop, see [Fast counting the number of equal bytes between two arrays](//stackoverflow.com/a/37936432).  You can SAD against a vector of `0x7f` and subtract a correction outside the loop, instead of needing `0-cmp()` to make it positive.

Answer (score 9):

Of course it can.

`pcmpeqb` compares two vectors of 16 bytes and produces a vector with zeros where they differed, and -1 where they match.  Use this to compare 16 bytes at a time, adding the result to an accumulator vector (make sure to accumulate the results of at most 255 vector compares to avoid overflow).  When you're done, there are 16 results in the accumulator.  Sum them and negate to get the number of equal elements.

If the lengths are very short, it will be hard to get a significant speedup from this approach.  If the lengths are long, then it will be worth pursuing.

Comment: Thanks, at least now I know that it's possible

Answer (score 3):

Auto-vectorization in current gcc is a matter of helping the compiler to understand that's easy to vectorize the code. In your case: it will understand the vectorization request if you remove the conditional and rewrite the code in a more imperative way:

```
    static inline int count(const char* string1, const char* string2, int size) {
            int r = 0;
            bool b;

            for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
                    b = (string1[j] == string2[j]);
                    r += b;
            }

            return r;
    }
```

In this case:

```
movdqa  16(%rsp), %xmm1
movl    $.LC2, %esi
pxor    %xmm2, %xmm2
movzbl  416(%rsp), %edx
movdqa  .LC1(%rip), %xmm3
pcmpeqb 224(%rsp), %xmm1
cmpb    %dl, 208(%rsp)
movzbl  417(%rsp), %eax
movl    $1, %edi
pand    %xmm3, %xmm1
movdqa  %xmm1, %xmm5
sete    %dl
movdqa  %xmm1, %xmm4
movzbl  %dl, %edx
punpcklbw   %xmm2, %xmm5
punpckhbw   %xmm2, %xmm4
pxor    %xmm1, %xmm1
movdqa  %xmm5, %xmm6
movdqa  %xmm5, %xmm0
movdqa  %xmm4, %xmm5
punpcklwd   %xmm1, %xmm6
```

(etc.)

Comment: I had a look at the rest of the disassembly, and, well, let's just say there's room for improvement.

Comment: Only about 5% faster with a large data set :( Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: simfoo, hand write a vectorized code with Stephen Canon's suggestion, where you separately accumulate 256 values before reducing to a separate final sum. This will factor out part of the code out of the inner loop.

Comment: GCC's effort here is really pathetic.  You might be able to get it to avoid all the widening conversions if you use an unsigned char inner accumulator, but at that point you might as well write some intrinsics.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2023, the best way to get compilers to generate good vector code is to iterate over chunks the size of your vector registers.  On AVX2 or above, those would be 256 bits, or 32 bytes.

```c
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdalign.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define ALIGNMENT 16U


size_t countEqualBytes(const size_t n, const uint8_t a[n], const uint8_t b[n]) {
    size_t sum = 0;
    size_t i = 0;

    if (n >= 32U) {
        const size_t sentinel = n - 31U;

        // #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum) schedule(static)
        for (i = 0; i < sentinel; i += 32U) {
            sum += (size_t)((a[i] == b[i]) +
              (a[i + 1] == b[i + 1]) +
              (a[i + 2] == b[i + 2]) +
              (a[i + 3] == b[i + 3]) +
              (a[i + 4] == b[i + 4]) +
              (a[i + 5] == b[i + 5]) +
              (a[i + 6] == b[i + 6]) +
              (a[i + 7] == b[i + 7]) +
              (a[i + 8] == b[i + 8]) +
              (a[i + 9] == b[i + 9]) +
              (a[i + 10] == b[i + 10]) +
              (a[i + 11] == b[i + 11]) +
              (a[i + 12] == b[i + 12]) +
              (a[i + 13] == b[i + 13]) +
              (a[i + 14] == b[i + 14]) +
              (a[i + 15] == b[i + 15]) +
              (a[i + 16] == b[i + 16]) +
              (a[i + 17] == b[i + 17]) +
              (a[i + 18] == b[i + 18]) +
              (a[i + 19] == b[i + 19]) +
              (a[i + 20] == b[i + 20]) +
              (a[i + 21] == b[i + 21]) +
              (a[i + 22] == b[i + 22]) +
              (a[i + 23] == b[i + 23]) +
              (a[i + 24] == b[i + 24]) +
              (a[i + 25] == b[i + 25]) +
              (a[i + 26] == b[i + 26]) +
              (a[i + 27] == b[i + 27]) +
              (a[i + 28] == b[i + 28]) +
              (a[i + 29] == b[i + 29]) +
              (a[i + 30] == b[i + 30]) +
              (a[i + 31] == b[i + 31]));
        }
    }

    for (; i<n; i++) {
        sum += (a[i] != b[i]);
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Clang 16 or ICX 2022 with `-std=c17 -O3 -march=x86-64-v4` are able to compile the critical loop of this to:

```
.LBB0_5:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        vmovdqu         ymm0, ymmword ptr [rsi + r10]
        vmovdqu         ymm1, ymmword ptr [rsi + r10 + 32]
        vmovdqu         ymm2, ymmword ptr [rsi + r10 + 64]
        vmovdqu         ymm3, ymmword ptr [rsi + r10 + 96]
        vpcmpeqb        k0, ymm0, ymmword ptr [rdx + r10]
        kmovd           ebx, k0
        popcnt          ebx, ebx
        add             rbx, rax
        vpcmpeqb        k0, ymm1, ymmword ptr [rdx + r10 + 32]
        kmovd           eax, k0
        popcnt          eax, eax
        add             rax, rbx
        vpcmpeqb        k0, ymm2, ymmword ptr [rdx + r10 + 64]
        kmovd           ebx, k0
        popcnt          ebx, ebx
        add             rbx, rax
        vpcmpeqb        k0, ymm3, ymmword ptr [rdx + r10 + 96]
        kmovd           eax, k0
        popcnt          eax, eax
        add             rax, rbx
        sub             r10, -128
        add             r9, -4
        jne             .LBB0_5
```

Which is this, unrolled four times:

```
.LBB0_8:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        vmovdqu         ymm0, ymmword ptr [r10 + rbx]
        vpcmpeqb        k0, ymm0, ymmword ptr [r9 + rbx]
        kmovd           ecx, k0
        popcnt          ecx, ecx
        add             rax, rcx
        add             rbx, 32
        cmp             r8, rbx
        jne            .LBB0_8
```

Although this uses an AVX512VL instruction, ICX can also vectorize for AVX or AVX2.

If you want to multi-thread the function as well as vectorize, add `-fiopenmp` on ICX/ICPX, or `-fopenmp` on Clang/GCC, and uncomment the `#pragma omp` directive.  Unfortunately, this only accepts a rigid format for the `for` statement, requiring a nested `if` block around the `for` (that otherwise could have been an extra clause in the loop condition: `n > 31U && i < n - 31U`).

Since x96 CPUs load data faster into registers faster when it’s aligned on 16-byte boundaries, you also want to declare your input arrays `alignas(ALIGNMENT)`.

This is as fast and as portable as I was able to get it.  However, you should see [this answer to a very similar question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/285458/136816) by @harold, which combines a 4,096-byte outer loop with a 32-byte inner loop, then a second loop to perform a vertical add.  The inner loop is also shorter by one instruction.

Comment: You mention AVX2 but then compile with `-march=x86-64-v4` to make AVX-512 code.  Also, if you want to avoid cache-line splits, you want data aligned by the register width.  Which is 32 or 64 if you're using YMM or ZMM registers; there's nothing special about 16-byte alignment unless you're using XMM registers (e.g. SSE or 128-bit AVX instructions).

Comment: @PeterCordes What I was trying to say there is that I wanted to use YMM registers on any ISA that supports AVX2 *or better*. I do say it uses an AVX512VL instruction. I appreciate the correction about alignment. I think I got that wrong on other answers as well.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Probably good to also mention that this auto-vectorized code isn't optimal for non-tiny arrays, especially with vectors less than 512-bit where comparing into a vector lets you subtract those 0/-1 elements from another vector of byte totals, so you do only about 3 uops of work per vector (load / micro-fused load+cmp if it avoided indexed addressing modes / `vpsubb`), rather than 5 (load / load+cmp / movmsk / popcnt / add) or 6 without micro-fusion.  To get compilers to emit good asm like that, you still need intrinsics. (See other answers)

Comment: Also related: [Counting differences between 2 buffers seems too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74415598) has my attempt from last year at something that auto-vectorizes.  I used an inner loop instead of manually unrolling, but clang reduces to scalar every 128 bytes somewhat inefficiently, using shuffles before an eventual `vpsadbw`, so it's worse than this.  Your answer only shows AVX-512 and neglects a Godbolt link (https://godbolt.org/z/3deoqMPbj) to make it faster for people to look at other options.  Yeah, with AVX2 it does `vpmovmskb` / `popcnt` but doesn't unroll your loop.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks! Your comments are always very informative.