# Common Characters Count In MIPS

Tags: assembly, count, character, mips

Given two strings, find the number of common characters between them.
Example: For s1 = "aabcc" and s2 = "adcaa", the output should be commonCharacterCount(s1, s2) = 3. Strings have 3 common characters - 2 "a"s and 1 "c".

It's pretty simple in C or Python, but is it possibly to write it in MIPS?

Comment: Nope, cannot be done in MIPS -- just kidding.  MIPS, like C and Python, is [Turing Complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness), which is just a fancy way of saying they can compute anything so are all equally powerful.

Comment: How would you do it in C?  Take your C approach and translate it to assembly, that's easier than writing it in assembly from scratch, when you don't know assembly.

Comment: Same question for x86 assembly: [How do I display the number of equal and different characters between two strings in assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71674283) - an answer there describes an algorithm that's slow but simple to implement in asm, destroying one of the input strings.  (As well as showing code for it: x86 `rep scasb` is just a byte search which you could do with a MIPS loop.)