# How to optimize array iteration in C for intel processors

Tags: arrays, c, x86, intel, simd

Tthe function `difference` may compute the amount of unequal elements of two `char` arrays of the length n:

```
size_t difference(size_t n, const char a[n], const char b[n]) {
    size_t res = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        res += a[i] != b[i];
    return res;
}
```

How can I make the iteration faster regarding the memory allocation of the arrays and the caches? Is there a way to use SSE intel intrinsics?

**EDIT:**

This is a standalone program which may use as few cycles as possible and use no compiler directives/pragmas.

Comment: Pragmas no, but intrinsics yes?

Comment: yes, that is correct @n.m.

Comment: In C++ you could try `std::count_if` with an execution policy of  `par_unseq` .

Comment: BTW Clang and GCC vectorize this, in different ways, but [both not great](https://godbolt.org/z/haveWMKT7). So yes, it is useful to do this manually.

Comment: Similar to [How to count character occurrences using SIMD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54541129/555045). Also based on compare, subtract, `_mm_sad_epu8` (but not on every iteration of the inner loop), etc. In your case you would load characters from two sources, and since you want to count non-matches, subtract from `n` in the end.

Comment: Too bad you say you can't use pragmas... OpenMP's SIMD mode would be useful.

Comment: @Shawn how do you make it do something useful? I tried it like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/obzYhvsaK) but that didn't do anything.

Comment: Like that, yes. I don't know what you mean by "didn't do anything", clearly both compilers vectorize the loop. clang better than gcc.

Comment: @Shawn it's vectorized the same way as without the pragma, apart from some unimportant details

Answer (score 0):

Make your n-byte array as blocks of 16 signed or unsigned 8-bit integers and use `__m128i _mm_cmpeq_epi8(__m128i a, __m128i b);`

When each byte of `a` is not equal to the corresponding byte of `b`, you will get a `0` in your result register. In the end of each block analysis, count number of zeros and add theme up to your `res` value.

Don't forget to include `emmintrin.h` header file.

**Note:** you may get a big performance boost, when your `n` is large.

Comment: You should not count the zeros and add them at the end of each block analysis. That uses needless cross-element operations…

Comment: … Instead: The compare instructions produce all 0 bits (comparison false) or all 1 bits (true) in each element, and all 1 bits is equivalent to −1. So we can simply do an element-wise add for at least 255 blocks. That will accumulate a count of the number of true results. After doing many blocks, we can accumulate those into wider elements and repeat and eventually combine into one total or we can accumulate them into one total, skipping the wider-element step. The number of false results can be computed from the number of true results and the number of elements compared.

Comment: Could also use `_mm_movemask_epi8()` and a popcount to get the number of matches.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: [Can counting byte matches between two strings be optimized using SIMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15598997) shows an example.  Counting mismatches is just `len - count_matches()`, so you just count the thing that's most efficient inside the loop: subtracting `0` or `-1` to count matches.  [How to count character occurrences using SIMD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54541129) has an AVX2 version.  (Comparing against `set1_epi8(key)` instead of loading from two arrays, otherwise the same problem.)

Comment: @PeterCordes FYI there is [cross-posted version of this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/285452/36018), you can weigh in there too